# Why is my IP address saying that I'm in a different state?

Tags: ip-address, geolocation

I live in PA and when I log into Facebook it says that my IP address location is in CA.

Is there a way that I can fix the address to where I actually live?

Comment: bear in mind geo-location is a bit of a snake-oil situation. Where you are and where you appear on the net are usually totally different. My ip shows up as a different location because i use the net via a leased line to a different country. That's before proxies get involved.

Answer (score 4):

Facebook among other sites use comprehensive IP GeoLocation databases. You cannot alter these databases, but maybe your ISP has given you an address which is listed as being a CA IP.

On a site like [IP2Location.com](http://www.ip2location.com/), you can check if the info provided about your IP address is correct.